# Import all bower packages

Tags: import, package, bower, main-bower-files

I want to be able to import all bower packages.
I've seen that it is possible by getting the JSON out of http://bower-component-list.herokuapp.com/   .
Unfortunately, this link is no longer maintained.
[image]
**Is there any other way/link?**
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **UPDATE December 2019**

## The new bower registry is on https://registry.bower.io/packages

---

Original post
OK, 
Apperantley, Bower changed their API.
In order to view all bower packages:
[**GO HERE**](https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages).

p.s - They have changes their API and now the only 2 things available from the API are:

- Package Name.
- Git Endpoint

e.g

> {"name":"jquery","url":"https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git"}